# Estimate the probability of the distribution of a sample

Tags: r, distributions

Suppose I have the sample of a continuous variable and I want to estimate the probability of that variable taking certain values. Suppose in addition that I estimate the density of that distribution with the density() function of R and the shape doesn't resemble any known distribution.

In that case, how can I estimate the probability of that variable taking some value? Can I just add up the values returned by the density() function on the range that I'm interested?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the ecdf() function. Let's try this with i.i.d draws from a N(500, 75).

```
set.seed(1)
temp<-rnorm(10000, 500, 75)
```

Now we calculate the empirical CDF and plot it...just to validate that it has the shape we would expect:

```
temp_cdf<-ecdf(temp) # generate empirical CDF for temp
plot(temp_cdf(seq(275, 725, length.out = 1000)),type='l') # plot cdf +/- 3 SDs from mean
```

Note that temp_cdf() is a function that will give you the CDF value at any value of temp. You can use this to calculate the probability that temp is between any given pair of values. Below we confirm that ~99.7% of the data are within 3 standard deviations of the mean.

```
> temp_cdf(725)-temp_cdf(275)
[1] 0.9972
```